# SQL Server is not showing any output

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using this code to verify user but it always displays 'User not found'. Whether I use complete select command with where clause or not. Answer is same every time. Although it shows some result in general but I can't match one result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Applicant : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlDataReader conReader = null;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Applicant ";
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", myid);
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", mypass);
                try
                {
                    conReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    bool _userfound = false;
                    while (conReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (conReader[0].ToString() == myid.ToString() && conReader[1].ToString() == mypass.ToString())
                        {
                            _userfound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (_userfound)
                        Response.Write("User Found");
                    else
                        Response.Write("User not Found");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ `select *` returns `username` as the first column and `userpassword` as the second? No user id or similar that may be first? Either way, for clarity, you should really not do `select *` and index by column number.

Comment: Just debug, and put some log messages every comparison you make, so you can know if the query results are OK .

Answer (score 3):

You should make the query complete, e.g.:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Applicant where UserName = @userName";
```

Only then will adding a parameter (of the same name) be substituted in the query.